# fabric.js canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I use fabric to do some editing.when i set a path for a image, `canvas.toDataURL()` work.but when i get the path of image from other place, it goes wrong.
  i really don't know why it goes wrong and how to solve it.

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" onchange="uploadImg()" name="xfile"/>
    <button onclick="addLocalImg()">localImg</button>
    <button onclick="produceImg()">toImg</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var imgPath;
    function uploadImg() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var name = $("input").val();
        formData.append("file", $("#uploadFile")[0].files[0]);
        formData.append("name", name);
        $.ajax({
            url: server+"/file/fileUp",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log("uploading...");
            },
            success: function (responseStr) {
                if (responseStr.code === 200) {
                    imgPath = responseStr.daoResult.path;
                    console.log("success" + responseStr);
                    imgShow(imgPath);
                } else {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            },
            error: function (responseStr) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }
    function imgShow(imgPath){
        var imgSrc = server + '/file/' + imgPath;
        var imgEl = $('<img />');
        imgEl.attr('src',imgSrc).load(function(){
            new fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSrc,function(oImg){
                canvas.add(oImg);
            })
        })
    }
    function addLocalImg(){
        var imgSrcPath = '../img/img1.jpg';
        var imgEl = $('<img />');
        imgEl.attr('src',imgSrcPath).load(function(){
            new fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSrcPath,function(oImg){
                canvas.add(oImg);
            })
        })
    }
    function produceImg(){
        var str = canvas.toDataURL();
        var imgstr = $('<img />');
        imgstr.attr('src',str).load(function(){
            $('body').append(imgstr);
        })
    }
</script>
```

[image: this is the error information]

Comment: Load image to your server and use same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine the problem being crossOrigin issues.

When you are loading a local image you do not have any problem.

When you load an image from a different `server` you have to specify the right crossOrigin value. For most of the situations a value `anonymous` is ok (if the server is configured in this way).

```
function imgShow(imgPath){
    var imgSrc = server + '/file/' + imgPath;
    var imgEl = $('<img />');
    imgEl.attr('src',imgSrc).load(function(){
        new fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSrc,function(oImg){
            canvas.add(oImg);
        }, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It must be a good answer.  But when I set a backgroundImage ,it still go the same wrong.So could you tell me how to do next?

Comment: Thank you again! I have solved this question.  The background also go right.